# Usage of WCF RIA Services without the Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

Can  WCF RIA Services be used without the Entity Framework (for example, if the datasource is no classical database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIA services is not tied to Entity framework.  RIA services uses the provider model to make it easy to plug in other datasources.
Here is a link to an example xml provider: [MSDN Custom MetaData Provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2659)